# How to keep save an input value in the same input bar until the user update it next time?

Tags: javascript, html, input, submit

I mean i want a button and an input so that when the user enter a value and click the button, the value is saved until next time the user enter a new value and update it.

```js
function Update() {
    var Update = document.getElementById("rate").submit;
}
```

```html
<form id="update" onsubmit="return false" method="post">
    <td><input class="rateContainer" value="Rate" disabled></td>
 <td><input type="number" id="rate"></input></td>
 <td><input type="submit" value ="Update" onclick="Update();" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: how long do you want to store it - ie how often is the user likely to update the value?

Comment: Where do you want to save it? Are you asking about how to save the data in the database? displaying it in the textarea after the page is refreshed? Or what?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Severin I want it to be displaying it in the textarea after the page is refreshed

Comment: That should probably be done using server side technology. How are you sending the page to the client? Are you just sending a static page or do you use some sort of dynamic page technology such as php/jsp/java templates/etc?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin I don't know what you are asking me about but you can have a look of how it looks in general if you go to www.rateconvertor.tk

Comment: @Pete The user will probably change it every 24 hours.

Comment: Then you are probably best storing it in a cookie if you do not have access to a database

Comment: @Pete Thanks but can you tell me how to do it, do I have to use any codes or what?

Comment: @muhammadshoaib do some research - there are plenty of examples. Have a go and if you get stuck with a particular problem then come back and post a question

Comment: @Pete I am doing research about it for like 4 days and now after i am stuck, I am asking this question. I've tried different ways but didn't work. If you know how to do it I would request you to tell me please, if not, thanks any way.

Comment: well then, you should post a more specific question - what have you tried? which part are you stuck on? What about it did not work.  This question looks like you have not tried anything and you are expecting us to code an answer for you.  This is not the forum for that kind of question, if you are wanting someone to do the code for you, then you are going to have to hire someone

Comment: @Pete well I am not asking you to code for me, I have posted the codes that I have got, I am just asking for some help and you think that I am making someone to code for me, I am not of that kind of person. I have only posted the part where I am stuck for some help, I have done what i could as you can see this at www.rateconvertor.tk, it is working but can just wanted to add a new feature to keep the rate save. If you think that I am asking you to code for me, then unfortunately you are wrong sir. i never said anywhere in my question or in comments to code, I just asked for help.

Comment: 1. nowhere in the code that you have shown is there any attempt to save the value.  2. I have told you to look into cookies so instead of wasting time on here, this is what you should be doing.  If you have already done this and it has not worked, then show your code and maybe we will be able to help.  3. this is my final comment good day and good luck to you sir